# Compile error on Mac and not Ubuntu

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, compilation, derby

I am trying to compile Apache Derby project on Mac OS. I am getting the following error:

```
class X not abstract and does not override abstract method Y
```

The project compiles normally on ubuntu. Is there any explanation for that?

- I am using java 1.6 on both OS
- I am compiling using ANT build file

Comment: My guess is that you're using different versions of some dependency. Have you looked at the specific class and method in question?

Comment: `build.xml` probably points to different dependencies for Linux/Mac, where the Mac one doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you mean that the build file under linux is seeing a different version of the class (maybe one that implements the method Y)?

Comment: @Dgrin91 Should I post the build.xml file?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you may be compiling different source code versions on the two different machines. Again, have you looked at the specific class and method in question? Does it *look* like there's a problem there?